# Затрудняюсь с разбором предложения на члены

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, cинтаксис

"Доброфест"- это фестиваль развлечений и музыки таких жанров как альтернатива, как и хип-хоп. Именно тут не могу понять, чем являются слова как и жанров в предложении? Я думаю слово "как"- это частица, а слово жанров - определение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  не могу понять, чем являются слова как и жанров в предложении? 
   Я думаю слово "как"- это частица, а слово жанров - определение.
```

*Как* - сравнительный союз, входит в сравнительный союзный оборот *таких, как*

"Доброфест"- это фестиваль развлечений и музыки (какой?)*таких жанров, как альтернатива, как и хип-хоп.* - всё это определение: и *жанров*, и 2 сравнительных оборота.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам!